# How to connect to PHP QucckBooks using consolibyte API

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am trying to integrate my QuickBooks accounting system to my PHP based web application.

The integration was working all good until I decided to use OAuth 2 tokens in order to connect PHP with Quickbooks online.

I was looking resources [here][1] and looked at the following steps.

1. Make a backup of your code
2. Make a backup of your existing OAuth v1.0 tokens
3. git clone the repository to get the new code
4. Make code changes as detailed below
5. Go get your Client ID and Client Secret from developer.intuit.com for your app

So, I did the backups and cloned the repository to get the new code.

I extracted the new repository and uploaded the code on my server.

I logged on to the developer.intuit.com and obtained my ‘`Productions tokens`’. So I have the ‘`Client ID`’ and ‘`Client Secret`’.

The next thing I did is opened `config_oauthv2.php` file and I have copied and pasted the `Client ID` and `Client Secret`.

```
$oauth_client_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
$oauth_client_secret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
```

Sandbox is set to `false` as I am using the productions tokens.

```
$sandbox = false;    // When you're using production tokens
```

I then changed the URL of Oauth handler, forward and menu to correct pages.

```
// This is the URL of your OAuth auth handler page
$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx/quickbooks-php-master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';

// This is the URL to forward the user to after they have connected to IPP/IDS via OAuth
$quickbooks_success_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx/quickbooks-php-master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php';

// This is the menu URL script
$quickbooks_menu_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx/quickbooks-php-master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';
```

I then updated the `$dsn` with connection to the database.

```
$dsn = 'mysqli://xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx';
```

I did not make any further changes so the rest of the code is the same as the repository.

```
// You should set this to an encryption key specific to your app
$encryption_key = 'bcde1234';

// Scope required
$scope = 'com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting ';

// The tenant that user is accessing within your own app
$the_tenant = 12345;
```

When I went to the **Index.php** URL. It displayed the following page.

[![index page][2]][2]

So I clicked “Connect to QuickBooks”, (I was hoping it will ask me to log into QuickBooks), but it displayed flowing page.

[![Error Image][3]][3]

Please, can you help me investigate the issue of why I cannot connect to Quickbooks?

Looks like when It goes to the `oauth.php`, it failed and returns

> could not build an authorisation. Oh, No something bad happened`.

My `oauth.php` page code is the same as what I cloned from the repository.

***EDIT response***

```
Trying to hit URL: https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_sandbox_configuration

   Did we disable SSL checks? false
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  curl_setopt(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in <b>C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\qbapi\quickbooks-php-master\docs\partner_platform\example_app_ipp_v3\troubleshooting.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />









Trying to hit URL: https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_configuration

   Did we disable SSL checks? false
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  curl_setopt(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in <b>C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\qbapi\quickbooks-php-master\docs\partner_platform\example_app_ipp_v3\troubleshooting.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />









Trying to hit URL: https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_sandbox_configuration

   Did we disable SSL checks? true
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  curl_setopt(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in <b>C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\qbapi\quickbooks-php-master\docs\partner_platform\example_app_ipp_v3\troubleshooting.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />



{  
   "issuer":"https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/op/v1",
   "authorization_endpoint":"https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
   "token_endpoint":"https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer",
   "userinfo_endpoint":"https://sandbox-accounts.platform.intuit.com/v1/openid_connect/userinfo",
   "revocation_endpoint":"https://developer.api.intuit.com/v2/oauth2/tokens/revoke",
   "jwks_uri":"https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/op/v1/jwks",
   "response_types_supported":[  
      "code"
   ],
   "subject_types_supported":[  
      "public"
   ],
   "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":[  
      "RS256"
   ],
   "scopes_supported":[  
      "openid",
      "email",
      "profile",
      "address",
      "phone"
   ],
   "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":[  
      "client_secret_post",
      "client_secret_basic"
   ],
   "claims_supported":[  
      "aud",
      "exp",
      "iat",
      "iss",
      "realmid",
      "sub"
   ]
}







Trying to hit URL: https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_configuration

   Did we disable SSL checks? true
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  curl_setopt(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in <b>C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\qbapi\quickbooks-php-master\docs\partner_platform\example_app_ipp_v3\troubleshooting.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />



{  
   "issuer":"https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/op/v1",
   "authorization_endpoint":"https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
   "token_endpoint":"https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer",
   "userinfo_endpoint":"https://accounts.platform.intuit.com/v1/openid_connect/userinfo",
   "revocation_endpoint":"https://developer.api.intuit.com/v2/oauth2/tokens/revoke",
   "jwks_uri":"https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/op/v1/jwks",
   "response_types_supported":[  
      "code"
   ],
   "subject_types_supported":[  
      "public"
   ],
   "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":[  
      "RS256"
   ],
   "scopes_supported":[  
      "openid",
      "email",
      "profile",
      "address",
      "phone"
   ],
   "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":[  
      "client_secret_post",
      "client_secret_basic"
   ],
   "claims_supported":[  
      "aud",
      "exp",
      "iat",
      "iss",
      "realmid",
      "sub"
   ]
}







php version: 7.0.30
mcrypt extension? true
  mcrypt module rijndael-256? NULL
curl extension? true
```

Comment: Can you grab the latest `troubleshooting.php` script (it has just been updated) and run that and post the output? https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/troubleshooting.php

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr. if you look in the  original question under the heading EDIT RESPONSE, I have pasted a response I got from [QuickBooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/troubleshooting.php]

Comment: Can you grab the latest version of `troubleshooting.php` and post the output from that? You're using an old version.

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr. I have updated my original question and I have output the response from the latest version of troubleshooting.php

Comment: Can you `git pull` on the latest code, and try again? The example has been updated with a change for `$oauth_state` which I believe may help you - https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php#L29

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr. I have updated the oauth.php code. I am still getting the same error. "Could not build an authorization URL.Oh no, something bad happened:"

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr. Is there any update on this. I am still getting the same error.