# Quickbooks PHP consolibyte API having authorization URL issues

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

I have previously asked this question, but the issue is still going. More details can be found on the below link. 
[How to connect to PHP QucckBooks using consolibyte API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934452/how-to-connect-to-php-qucckbooks-using-consolibyte-api).

I have a PHP application and I would like to connect QB online with my application using the consolibyte API.

I have created a repository and obtained the tokens.

But when I click on the "Connect to Quick books"

I get error

> "Could not build an authorization URL.Oh no, something bad happened"

**Code:**

```
// Require the library code
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../QuickBooks.php';

// Your OAuth consumer key and secret (Intuit will give you both of these when you register an Intuit app)
//
// IMPORTANT:
//  To pass your tech review with Intuit, you'll have to AES encrypt these and
//  store them somewhere safe.
//
// The OAuth request/access tokens will be encrypted and stored for you by the
//  PHP DevKit IntuitAnywhere classes automatically.
$oauth_client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$oauth_client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

// If you're using DEVELOPMENT TOKENS, you MUST USE SANDBOX MODE!!!  If you're in PRODUCTION, then DO NOT use sandbox.
//$sandbox = true;     // When you're using development tokens
$sandbox = false;    // When you're using production tokens


// This is the URL of your OAuth auth handler page
$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'http://xxxxxxxqb/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';

// This is the URL to forward the user to after they have connected to IPP/IDS via OAuth
$quickbooks_success_url = 'http://xxxxxxxxqb/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.phpf';

// This is the menu URL script
$quickbooks_menu_url = 'http://xxxxxxxxx/qb/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';


// This is a database connection string that will be used to store the OAuth credentials
// $dsn = 'pgsql://username:password@hostname/database';
// $dsn = 'mysql://username:password@hostname/database';
$dsn = 'mysqli://xxxxxxx@localhost/xxxxxx';

// You should set this to an encryption key specific to your app
$encryption_key = 'bcde1234';

// Scope required
$scope = 'com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting ';

// The tenant that user is accessing within your own app
$the_tenant = 12345;
```

**EDIT**

```
/**
 * Intuit Partner Platform configuration variables
 *
 * See the scripts that use these variables for more details.
 *
 * @package QuickBooks
 * @subpackage Documentation
 */

// Turn on some error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Require the library code
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../QuickBooks.php';

// Your OAuth consumer key and secret (Intuit will give you both of these when you register an Intuit app)
//
// IMPORTANT:
//  To pass your tech review with Intuit, you'll have to AES encrypt these and
//  store them somewhere safe.
//
// The OAuth request/access tokens will be encrypted and stored for you by the
//  PHP DevKit IntuitAnywhere classes automatically.
$oauth_client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$oauth_client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


// If you're using DEVELOPMENT TOKENS, you MUST USE SANDBOX MODE!!!  If you're in PRODUCTION, then DO NOT use sandbox.
//$sandbox = true;     // When you're using development tokens
$sandbox = false;    // When you're using production tokens
x

// This is the URL of your OAuth auth handler page
$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx/qb/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';

// This is the URL to forward the user to after they have connected to IPP/IDS via OAuth
$quickbooks_success_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/qb/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php';

// This is the menu URL script
$quickbooks_menu_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/qb/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl

// This is a database connection string that will be used to store the OAuth credentials
// $dsn = 'pgsql://username:password@hostname/database';
// $dsn = 'mysql://username:password@hostname/database';
$dsn = 'mysqli://xxxxx:xxxxxx@localhost/xxxxx';

// You should set this to an encryption key specific to your app
$encryption_key = 'bcde1234';

// Scope required
$scope = 'com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting ';

// The tenant that user is accessing within your own app
$the_tenant = 12345;

// Initialize the database tables for storing OAuth information
if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
    // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
}

// Instantiate our Intuit Anywhere auth handler
//
// The parameters passed to the constructor are:
//  $oauth_version          QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere::OAUTH_V2 or QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere::OAUTH_V1
//  $dsn
//  $oauth_consumer_key     Intuit will give this to you when you create a new Intuit Anywhere application at AppCenter.Intuit.com
//  $oauth_consumer_secret  Intuit will give this to you too
//  $this_url               This is the full URL (e.g. http://path/to/this/file.php) of THIS SCRIPT
//  $that_url               After the user authenticates, they will be forwarded to this URL
//
$IntuitAnywhere = new QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere(
    QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere::OAUTH_V2,
    $sandbox,
    $scope,
    $dsn,
    $encryption_key,
    $oauth_client_id,
    $oauth_client_secret,
    $quickbooks_oauth_url,
    $quickbooks_success_url);

// Are they connected to QuickBooks right now?
if ($IntuitAnywhere->check($the_tenant) and
    $IntuitAnywhere->test($the_tenant))
{
    // Yes, they are
    $quickbooks_is_connected = true;

    // Set up the IPP instance
    $IPP = new QuickBooks_IPP($dsn, $encryption_key);

    // Get our OAuth credentials from the database
    $creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_tenant);

    // Tell the framework to load some data from the OAuth store
    $IPP->authMode(
        QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTHV2,
        $creds);

    if ($sandbox)
    {
        // Turn on sandbox mode/URLs
        $IPP->sandbox(true);
    }

    // Print the credentials we're using
    //print_r($creds);

    // This is our current realm
    $realm = $creds['qb_realm'];

    // Load the OAuth information from the database
    $Context = $IPP->context();

    // Get some company info
    $CompanyInfoService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_CompanyInfo();
    $quickbooks_CompanyInfo = $CompanyInfoService->get($Context, $realm);
}
else
{
    // No, they are not
    $quickbooks_is_connected = false;
}
```

**Oauth.php**

```
/**
 * Example of OAuth authentication for an Intuit Anywhere application
 *
 *
 *
 * @package QuickBooks
 * @subpackage Documentation
 */

/**
 * Require the QuickBooks library
 */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../QuickBooks.php';


// For OAuth2 (all new application, and what you should be migrating to)
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config_oauthv2.php';

// For old/legacy applications
//require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config_oauthv1.php';

// You can define your own OAuth state if you want
//   (useful for associating the initial OAuth request with the response you get back)
$oauth_state = md5(microtime(true));

// Try to handle the OAuth request
if ($IntuitAnywhere->handle($the_tenant, $oauth_state))
{
    ; // The user has been connected, and will be redirected to $that_url automatically.
}
else
{
    // If this happens, something went wrong with the OAuth handshake
    die('Oh no, something bad happened: ' . $IntuitAnywhere->errorNumber() . ': ' . $IntuitAnywhere->errorMessage());
}
```

Comment: Intuit requires `httpS://` for production OAuth URL, and yet you're using `http://` instead. This will not work. Why does your OAuth URL not match what you entered into https://developer.intuit.com ?

Comment: Also, please post the rest of that file.

Comment: Hi @KeithPalmerJr. I have tried with `https://`, still the same issue. I have added the rest of the code in the original question.

Comment: Can you also post `oauth.php` ? Are you using the latest on GitHub?

Comment: I have posted the `oauth.php` code under the heading "oauth.php" in the original question. I am using the latest from Github.